# Why the following attack in common modulus RSA works?

Tags: rsa, public-key

Suppose that i share a common modulus  $N$ with two users $u_1$ and $u_2$ with public, secret keys ($e_a,d_a$), ($e_b,d_b$).
Why then  $gcd(V,e_b)=1$ where $V=d_a*e_a-1/$W and $W=gcd(e_b,d_a*e_a-1)$  and as a consequence with extended euclidena algorithm i compute $α,β$ such that $α*e_b+β*V=1$ and it comes that $α=d_b$

Answer (score 1):

One correction to your question: it's not necessarily true that your procedure will give you $\alpha = d_b$; however, the $\alpha$ you do get will work as a private key corresponding to $e_b$, just not necessarily the exact value that the user $u_2$ has.

With that in mind, here's an outline of why that is so:

First of all, two keys $(e, d)$ will work as corresponding public/secret exponents with an RSA modulus $N$ if and only if $e \cdot d \equiv 1 \space ( \bmod \space\lambda(N) )$, where $\lambda(N) = lcm(p-1, q-1)$.

So, we can restate the problem as: given values $(e_a, d_a)$ with $e_a \cdot d_a \equiv 1 \space ( \bmod \space\lambda(N) )$, and a value $e_b$, find a value $\alpha$ such that $e_b \cdot \alpha \equiv 1 \space ( \bmod \space\lambda(N) )$ (even if we don't know the value of $\lambda(N)$)

Now, the condition $e_a \cdot d_a \equiv 1 \space ( \bmod \space\lambda(N) )$ is precisely equivalent to the statement that there exists an integer $k$ such that $e_a \cdot d_a - 1 = k \cdot \lambda(N)$; let us call the value $k \cdot \lambda(N) = V$.  Note that, even though we don't know the values of either $k$ or $\lambda(N)$, we can compute $V$.

Now, given that we know the values $e_b, V$, we can certainly run the Extended Euclidean algorithm, and find values $\alpha, \beta$ with $\alpha \cdot e_b + \beta \cdot V = 1$.  Now, if reduce both sides modulo $\lambda(N)$, we find that $(\alpha \cdot e_b + \beta \cdot V) \bmod \lambda(N) = (\alpha \cdot e_b) \bmod \lambda(N) + 0 = 1$ (because $V$ is a multiple of $\lambda(N)$), and so $\alpha$ does meet the requirements of a private key corresponding to $e_b$.

Now, a few notes:

- The above argument shows that the result is correct, however it doesn't say why someone would happen to stumble upon it in the first place.  Actually, it's not nearly as mysterious as it would seem; what we want is $e_b^{-1} \bmod V$, that is, the multiplicative inverse of $e_b$ modulo $V$, and the Extended Euclidean method is the standard way to compute that.
- The algorithm you have divides $V$ by $W$.  It turns out that doesn't change anything; $W$ will be relatively prime to $\lambda(N)$; we know this because $W$ is a divisor of $e_b$, and $e_b$ must be relatively prime to $\lambda(N)$.  So, dividing $V$ by $W$ effectively makes $V = (k/W) \cdot \lambda(N)$; $(k/W)$ is an integer (which is all we cared about $k$ anyways), and so it doesn't change the above argument.
- If someone does have a $(e,d)$ public/private key pair for a modulus $N$, it turns out that they can also efficiently factor $N$; however, the explination for how to do that would require a bit more work to explain.

Comment: I don't understand the involvement of $\lambda(N) = lcm(p-1, q-1)$. As far as i know $e \cdot d \equiv 1 mod\phi(N)$

Comment: @curious: actually, as I stated, $e \cdot d \equiv 1 \bmod \lambda(N)$ is both necessary and sufficient.  To show that $\phi(N)$ is not necessary, consider the toy example with $e=3$, $d=11$, $N=85$.  Here, $(M^e)^d \equiv M (\bmod N)$ for all $M$; however, $e \cdot d \neq 1 \bmod \phi(N)$

Comment: So why in every book, research paper, textbook, the requirement is $e \cdot d \equiv 1 \phi(N)$ and not $e \cdot d \equiv 1 \lambda(N)$

Comment: and why $gcd(e_b,V)=1$ , according to your notation where  $V=e_a \cdot d_a -1$

Comment: @curious: you've read every book, research paper and textbook on RSA???  In any case, that's not true; for example, FIPS 186-3 (the US government statement on how to do, among other things, RSA), it has $1 = (ed) \bmod lcm(p-1,q-1)$ (see B.3.1, requirement 3).  Showing that $e \cdot d \equiv 1 \bmod \lambda(N)$ is sufficient is actually fairly easy (it's mostly Chinese Remainder Theorem and Fermat's Little Theorem); to show it is necessary requires digging a bit more into the number theory.

Comment: @curious: I never said $gcd(e_b,V)=1$.  My original argument had $e_a \cdot d_a - 1 = V = k \cdot \lambda(N)$, for some integer k (and we don't care what the value of that integer is).  Inserting $W$ makes this $(e_a \cdot d_a - 1) = V = (K/W) \cdot \lambda(N)$, where $(K/W)$ is an integer; that fulfills all the requirements that we needed for $K$; hence making that change doesn't impact the remaining argument.  It was just easier to write out the reasoning without $W$; inserting it doesn't invalidate the argument.

Comment: "Computing the RSA Secret Key Is Deterministic Polynomial Time Equivalent to Factoring" from May explains, how to get $(p,q)$ from $(e,d)$ in poly time. This means, $u_1$ will just factorize $N$ and calculate the private key of $u_2$.

Comment: You said that even if we do not know $\lambda(N)$ we can learn $k \lambda(N)$ which is true. But then how you apply the $mod(\lambda(N))$ operation?

Comment: @curious: you never need to; instead what you do is find $d'_b = e_b^{-1} \bmod V$; the resulting value will work as a decryption exponent for $e_b$, even though it is likely not to be the minimal value to do so.